# If - Controller in JMeter is throwing jmeter.functions.JavaScript: Error processing Javascript

Tags: if-statement, jmeter

I am calling a variable from bean shell, and then using the variable in if controller. My if condition is :
`${__javaScript(${message_template_id} == request})}`

It is throwing the following error:

```
jmeter.functions.JavaScript: Error processing Javascript: [request == request}]
 org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: syntax error (<cmd>#1)
```

Please let me know if there is any solution for this.

Comment: You seem to have an extra closing curly brace in your condition.  Remove the one here: `request}`

Answer (score 0):

To compare string variables try to use:
${__javaScript('${var}'!="string")};

To compare integer:
${__javaScript(${var}>0)};